# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textappearance' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

I am using the following xml file and I find the error above in textview line and another error "hardcoded string send should use @stringresource"

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textappearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">

  <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Send">


 </Button></TextView></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's case-sensitive: use `android:textAppearance`, instead. The second is a warning, not an error. Gunoi's answer was good. I don't know why he deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error you should write android:textAppearance. And for the second, it should be a warning saying to use strings declared in res/values/strings.xml

Comment: No problem. Please select my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please close the `<TextView>` properly before the button. And also verify whether you are using the right Android API target version.